# datepicker - limit start & end dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a date controller which I have a few blocked dates which works well. But I am now trying to limit the start and end date, but it seems not to be working at all. Hope some one can help me. Here are my code:

```
var array = ['2017-7-1', '2017-7-2'];
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: '+2D', 
    maxDate: '2017-6-20',
    todayHighlight: true,   
    autoclose: true,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var cur_day = date.getDate();
        var cur_month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var cur_year = date.getFullYear();
        var cur_date = cur_year + '-' + cur_month + '-' + cur_day;

        if (array.indexOf(cur_date) > -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

SOLVED:

My bad. I am using the bootstrap-datepicker, so should instead be using startDate & endDate for this settings instead.

hope this helps others in future. Thanks

Comment: can you post a working example

Comment: my bad. I am using the bootstrap-datepicker, so should instead be using startDate & endDate for this settings instead. hope this helps others in future. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use either a new date object or supply an integer for days in reference to current value as something like this below

```
minDate: 2
maxDate: new Date(2010,11,12)
```

**Edit**: As this is a bootstrap datepicker, it should be

```
`startDate` and `endDate`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set min & max date around current data in the below way.

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
            minDate: 0, 
            maxDate: '+1' 
 });
```

The above snippet, restricts min date to today's date while max date to +1 from current date.

Hope this helps!!